Bury J-box with splices inside plaster wall if documented?
Can you extend a single circuit by splicing on a new length of wire in a junction box and then burying that box inside of a plaster wall, as long as you document that the splice is buried there?
I saw this recently online when a master electrician (40+ years experience) was showing how to move a light fixture in an old plaster wall and needed to extend the wires in the wall to reach the new location. He solidly spliced on a new length of wires inside of a 4" metal junction box with proper clamps on the side and a well secured cover. He then pushed the box into the wall and repaired the hole by plastering over it. It is not accessible in any way anymore without cutting a new hole in the plaster.
He made the offhand comment that he hears the claim online frequently that it's not possible to do what he just did but that that's not true -- it is very frequently done in the trades and code permits it as long as the location of the splice is documented/noted.
This is in New York state, very likely, if it matters.
What might he be referring to? I cannot find anything similar in my reading of the NEC or IRC and searching for code questions on the web is pointless these days.
ANSWER:
He was referring to "as built" documentation, which is commonly required on commercial builds. I'm told that with commercial electrical, they commonly bury junction boxes in ceilings and such and that is okay as long as the box is noted properly in the "as built" drawings that were already required.

All that I have ever learned about boxes does not support the idea that they can be buried in a wall if documented.   If that is true, then what is the definition of "documented"  A drawing inside the breaker box?  A map of the footprint of the home with any hidden boxes noted and the same recorded as an attachment to the deed?  Or a piece of tape with "elect box here" placed on the wall?    The idea that the documentation can survive more than on or 2 owners is curious at best.

Certain types of splices can be buried in a box inside a wall and still meet code.

That's a clear violation. See the linked dupe.

@RMDman — it’s documented in the online video.

@Pete Becker, ...and where is that online video placed in the home, so that one knows that there is a buried box?
